# Difrentes prioridades de LocationEngine de Mapbox en Android

Tags: java, android, mapbox

Para obtener posiciones con el control `mapbox` se usa `LocationEngine` veo que se puede especificar la prioridad, es decir el muestreo de datos de localización.

```
locationEngine = LocationSource.getLocationEngine(this);
locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

Aquí [LocationEnginePriority](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/mapbox-java/libandroid-telemetry/2.1.0/com/mapbox/services/android/telemetry/location/LocationEnginePriority.html) que solo dice los tipos:

- BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
- HIGH_ACCURACY
- LOW_POWER
- NO_POWER

Buscando por dentro de su código [mapbox-java](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/mapbox/libandroid-telemetry/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/telemetry/location/AndroidLocationEngine.java):

```
private void updateCurrentProvider() {
    // We might want to explore android.location.Criteria here.
    if (priority == LocationEnginePriority.NO_POWER) {
      currentProvider = LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER;
    } else if (priority == LocationEnginePriority.LOW_POWER) {
      currentProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    } else if (priority == LocationEnginePriority.BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY) {
      currentProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    } else if (priority == LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY) {
      currentProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    }
}
```

¿Me pregunto que diferencia hay en usar `LOW_POWER` con el `BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`? los dos a primera instancia obtienen la posiciones de `NETWORK_PROVIDER`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traducción sobre el post encontrado:

> Los desarrolladores deben decidir cuanta energía utilizar para calcular la localización utilizando una combinación de elementos Wi-Fi, redes móviles y  sensores para calcular la localización.

Existiendo esta diferencia en los dos elementos que comentas

- PRIORITY_LOW_POWER (~10km precisión de ciudad)
- PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY (~100m precisión bloqueada)

puedes encontrar el post completo en: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768048/priority-low-power-vs-priority-balanced-power-accuracy-for-google-play-service-v)

Del api de google:

**public static final int PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY**

Para añadir el nivel "block" ("bloqueada") de precisión

Se considera una precisión de 100 metros. Usando este tipo de rpecisión a menudo consumes menos energía

**public static final int PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY**

Establece el mayor nivel de precisión. Devolviendo la localización más exacta

**public static final int PRIORITY_LOW_POWER**

Establece la precisión "city" ("ciudad")

Se considera una precisión de 10 km. Consume poca energía

**public static final int PRIORITY_NO_POWER**

Devolverá la mejor localización posible teniendo en cuenta un consumo 0 de energía extra

No se devolverán ubicaciones a menos que un cliente diferente haya solicitado actualizaciones de ubicación, en cuyo caso esta solicitud actuará como un oyente pasivo en esas ubicaciones.